# Hover applies to all element when hover on one ? Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I am not sure why hover applies to all elements when hover on one element.

```
 {isClicked && ( 
            <div className='bg-slate-400 text-white p-6 absolute before: top-7 before: -left-7 flex flex-col gap-2 justify-center'>
                {countries.map((country, index) => (
                        <p 
                            key={index}
                            className='hover:scale-110 hover:underline'
                        >
                            {country}
                        </p>
                ))}
            </div>)}
```

So, I changed the style when hover:

```
  <div className='bg-slate-400 text-white p-6 absolute before: top-7 before: -left-7 flex flex-col gap-2 justify-center'>
                <h3>All UK</h3>
                {countries.map((country, index) => (
                        <p 
                            key={index}
                            className='hover: bg-slate-800'
                        >
                            {country}
                        </p>
                ))}
            </div>)}
```

And now hover applies to all p elements even when I not hover over them.

Why does happens ? What to change so that hover applies only to one element that is hovered on ?

And if a country name contains 2 words, the second word wraps on new row. I kept changing width and height but still happens. I saw on tailwind doc to use whitespace-nowrap but affects all elements and are displayed in a row and not in column all dough flex direction in column.

The whole component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const countries = ['England, Scotland, Wales, NorthemIreland']

const Location = () => {
    const [loc, setLoc] = useState({country: '', region: ''})
    const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState('false')

    return (
        <div 
            className='text-white relative'
            onClick={() => setIsClicked(!isClicked)}
            >
         Location
         {isClicked && ( 
            <div className='bg-slate-400 text-white p-6 absolute before: top-7 before: -left-7 flex flex-col gap-2 justify-center'>
                <h3>All UK</h3>
                {countries.map((country, index) => (
                        <p 
                            key={index}
                            className='hover: bg-slate-800'
                        >
                            {country}
                        </p>
                ))}
            </div>)}
        
        </div>
    )
}

export default Location
```

Comment: I think that the bug is from tailwind and not react. maybe is just a typo `hover:  bg-slate-100` needs to not have a space between. so the correct version is `hover:bg-slate-100`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see in your code is the use of a tailwind class in your HTML elements, tailwind utility class should be used without space.

Your use of class:

```
// wrong implementation
  <p key={index} className='hover: bg-slate-800'>{country}</p>

// Right implementation
<p key={index} className='whitespace-nowrap hover:bg-slate-800'>{country}</p>
```

And for the second issue you need, as per your code snippet, the country array is incorrect each country name should be treated as a different value, once you fix your second issue should be fixed.

```
// This
const countries = ['England, Scotland, Wales, NorthemIreland']

// To This
const countries = ["England", "Scotland", "Wales", "Northen Ireland"];
```

Also, I saw you are using a boolean state as a string, which will fail when you update the `isClicked` state

```
// This
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState('false')

// TO This
const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false)
```

For a better experience with a tailwind, try installing a tailwind extension if you are using a vscode editor.

Hope this works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

it is because you used map function and uses onclicked which refers to all values you mapped so all values got hovered

Answer (score 1):

1. Change `hover: bg-slate-800` to `hover:bg-slate-800`
2. Make sure the index is unique for every list item, try `console.log(index)`. To check if the item is having unique index.
3. To avoid country on longer name going to the next line. Use `whitespace-nowrap`

   Example:

   ```
   <div class="before: before: absolute -left-7 top-7 m-4 flex flex-col justify-center gap-2 bg-slate-400 p-6 text-white">
    <h3>All UK</h3>

    <p key="1" class="whitespace-nowrap hover:bg-slate-800">India</p>
    <p key="2" class="whitespace-nowrap hover:bg-slate-800">Australia</p>
    <p key="3" class="whitespace-nowrap hover:bg-slate-800">West Indies</p>
    <p key="4" class="whitespace-nowrap hover:bg-slate-800">SOth America</p>
    <p key="5" class="whitespace-nowrap hover:bg-slate-800">Very long country name</p>
   </div>
   ```

Output:

[image]

*The screen shot was captured without the capture of mouse pointer*

Comment: Yes. It was from index. I console log the value of index and it was 0 and country was all countries. I changed countries to an array of objects and it worked. Thank you